# Show the differences of the 2 java objects using the Audit Trial

Tags: java

Hi I have implemented java code for finding the difference of 2 java objects using the comparator interface with the help of few folks here. Now i want to implement the code which has to log(Audit Trial) all the differences between 2 objects. My code is here,

```
public class A implements Comparator<A> {
    private int id1, id2; 
    /* setters and getters for id1 and id2 */                 

    public int compare(A o1, A o2) {
        if (o1 == o2) {
            return 0;
        } else if (o1 == null) {
            return -1;
        } else if (o2 == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (o1.getId1() != o2.getId1()) {
            return o1.getId1() - o2.getId1();
        } else {
            return o1.getId2() - o2.getId2();
        }
    }   
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        A obj1 = new A();
        obj1.id1 = 10;
        obj1.id2 = 20;

        A obj2 = new A();
        obj2.id1 = 10;
        obj2.id2 = 30;

        if (obj1.compare(obj1, obj2) == 0) {
            System.out.println("EQUALS");
        } else {
            System.out.println("NOT EQUALS");
        }
       }

 Please advise me how i can implement the code for AuditTrial here. Thanks.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `java Reflection` API to achieve this.I have done this earlier where for Audit Trail we can not use `tigers`.

Pass the array of properties where you want to compare it takes the two beans of same type.

```
public static List<String[]> compareBeans(Object bean1, Object bean2,
        String... propertyNames) throws IntrospectionException,
        IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
    List<String[]> lList=new ArrayList<String[]>();
    Set<String> names = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(propertyNames));
    BeanInfo beanInfo = Introspector.getBeanInfo(bean1.getClass());

    for (PropertyDescriptor prop : beanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors()) {
        if (names.remove(prop.getName())) {
            Method getter = prop.getReadMethod();
            Object value1 = getter.invoke(bean1);
            Object value2 = getter.invoke(bean2);
            if (value1 == value2
                    || (value1 != null && value1.equals(value2))) {
                continue;
   // if values are equal then no need to log it in database.
            } else {

                String[] changeArray=new String[4];
                changeArray[0]=getTableName(bean1);
                changeArray[1]=prop.getName();
                changeArray[2]=value1.toString();
                changeArray[3]=value2.toString();
                lList.add(changeArray);

            }
        }
    }

    for(String[] s:lList)
        System.out.println(s[0]+" , "+ s[1]+" , "+s[2]+" , "+s[3] );
    return lList;
}
   // Above code will compare two beans and give you the difference .

   // below method get the class name and then get the table name.
private static String getTableName(Object obj){

    String qualiFiedName=obj.getClass().getName();
    String name=qualiFiedName.substring(qualiFiedName.lastIndexOf(".")+1);

    // Your logic to get table name mapped with corresponding object

    return name;

}
```

Once you got all the details where in which column , table the changes are easily your AuditDao can log these changes in database.

Hopefully i have answered your question.

Comment: Hi Ami, How i can implement the above logic (Reflection API) in to my above code. Please advise on this. Thanks.

Comment: @Dhruthi Once you pass two  same type object but differ in state above class will print the difference between two objects then you can log those in table .

Comment: Hi amic Thanks for the reply. i have go through the steps which you explained here. But for my requirement i am not sure how exactly i have to pass my two objects to the compareBeans method because here the third parameter i have to pass is propertyNames. In the above code which i have written ie.compare(A o1, A o2), here i will be knowing the differences of two objects. and from here after how exactly i have to pass these objects to the compareBeans method to achieve Audit Trail. I mean how i can store these objects in the table. Please advise on this.